# Is that possible to break Sandboxing on non jailbreaked iPhone?

Tags: ios, sandbox

My app is not target for App Store, and it should get info of Phone Call Records while can't made it (by accessing phone record data base files) because of Sandboxing limitation.

Is that possible to break Sandboxing on non jailbreaked iPhone? Namely access the file outside apps directory in a normal iPhone? (via private framework or any other methods?)

I have googled for few days, and no clue...

Any ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried with adhoc distribution? as it is same as that of appstore build?

Comment: Did you try using NSFileManager and/or NSURL pointing to files?